# How to use ffmpeg command for Android

Tags: android, android-ndk, ffmpeg, java-native-interface

I would like to separate `audio` and `video` from given `input video file`.I have build `ffmpeg` sos for Android using http://www.roman10.net/how-to-build-ffmpeg-with-ndk-r9/ this link.

**generated SOS**

```
 libavcodec-56.so,libavfilter-5.so,libavformat-56.so,libavutil-54.so,libswscale-3.so
```

ffmpeg command for separate `video file(doesn't contain audio)` from input video file

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -map 0:v -codec copy output.mkv
```

I know the `command` which we have used in `command prompt` to get the desired output

I dont know how to call the ffmpeg command from Android Java Native method.and also dont know about write a JNI wrapper for this command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are doing the `ffmpeg` library porting to android, not the `ffmpeg` binary format. You need to reference the `ffmpeg` library documents to call APIs exported in the library instead invoking the `ffmpeg` command.

You could use `system()` or `exec()` Linux C api to call the command `ffmpeg` in JNI, but i don't think this is the way you are looking for.

The article link you posted already provide the [examples](https://github.com/roman10/android-ffmpeg-tutorial), have you checked?

Comment: please advice which type will provide better perfomance.`ffmpeg` binary format or `ffmpeg` library API.

Comment: the library api will have better performance since it doesn't have to create new process.

Comment: I am not clear about `ffmpeg` library API for separate audio/video. so I am going with ffmpeg binary executable. is any better tutorial for ffmpeg android binary

Comment: @Manoj the usage for android binary would be the same the usage in PC, if you cross-compile ffmpeg binary for android platform. So the best tutorial might be the manual in PC. `man ffmpeg`

Comment: These examples are not working and making errors also there's no proper guidance or help about these tutorials. Is there any step by step guide to use these in android studio gradle project ?